Spring Cloud Sleuth Not Working with OpenTelemetry: Version Conflicts with Spring Boot 2.x
I am using spring boot 2.7.3 to add observability through open telemetry ( manual instrumentation ).
Things I have done so far.
Added these dependencies in pom.xml
   io.opentelemetry.instrumentation
   opentelemetry-logback-appender-1.0
   1.31.0-alpha
  
  
   io.opentelemetry
   opentelemetry-sdk
   1.31.0
  
  
   io.opentelemetry.instrumentation
   opentelemetry-instrumentation-api-semconv
   1.31.0-alpha
  
  
   io.opentelemetry
   opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-common
   1.31.0

These are existing dependencies
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-brave</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-otlp</artifactId>
            <version>1.23.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-autoconfigure -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-sdk-metrics</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Micrometer Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Micrometer Prometheus Registry -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot Actuator for exposing metrics -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

are these are the configuration beans
    @Bean
    public Tracer tracer(OpenTelemetry openTelemetry) {
        return openTelemetry.getTracer("service-name");
    }
    
        @Bean
        OpenTelemetry openTelemetry(SdkLoggerProvider sdkLoggerProvider, SdkTracerProvider sdkTracerProvider, ContextPropagators contextPropagators) {
            OpenTelemetrySdk openTelemetrySdk = OpenTelemetrySdk.builder()
                    .setLoggerProvider(sdkLoggerProvider)
                    .setTracerProvider(sdkTracerProvider)
                    .setPropagators(contextPropagators)
                    .build();
            OpenTelemetryAppender.install(openTelemetrySdk);
            return openTelemetrySdk;
        }

        @Bean
        SdkLoggerProvider otelSdkLoggerProvider(Environment environment, ObjectProvider logRecordProcessors) {
            String applicationName = environment.getProperty("spring.application.name", "application");
            Resource springResource = Resource.create(Attributes.of(ResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME, applicationName));
            SdkLoggerProviderBuilder builder = SdkLoggerProvider.builder()
                    .setResource(Resource.getDefault().merge(springResource));
            logRecordProcessors.orderedStream().forEach(builder::addLogRecordProcessor);
            return builder.build();
        }

        @Bean
        LogRecordProcessor otelLogRecordProcessor() {
            return BatchLogRecordProcessor
                    .builder(
                            OtlpGrpcLogRecordExporter.builder()
                                    .setEndpoint("http://localhost:4317")
                                    .build())
                    .build();
        }

so Now opentelemetry-logback-appender-1.0 ask me to bump my
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentelemetry.instrumentation</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentelemetry-instrumentation-api-semconv</artifactId>
    <version>{version}</version>
</dependency>

version >= 1.29.0 but when I update, then spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-autoconfigure shows incompatibility with 1.29.0-alpha and ask to demote it to 1.22.0-alpha.
This is causing circular dependency for me, what should be the best practive to use spring cloud sleuth with Open Telemetry.
Note: I am trying to add Loki integration with my service following this blog
https://medium.com/@ahmadalammar/comprehensive-observability-in-spring-boot-using-opentelemetry-prometheus-grafana-tempo-and-e08842ae96be
This is my docker-compose file to give a hint what I am trying to achieve
version: "4.32"

services:
  collector:
    image: otel/opentelemetry-collector:0.72.0
    command: [ "--config=/etc/otel-config.yml" ]
    volumes:
      - ./otel-collector/otel-config.yml:/etc/otel-config.yml
    ports:
      - "4317:4317"  # OTLP gRPC endpoint
      - "55681:55681" # OTLP HTTP endpoint
      - "8889:8889" # Prometheus exporter metrics
    depends_on:
      - jaeger-service

  prometheus:
    container_name: prometheus
    image: prom/prometheus
    command:
      - --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
      - --enable-feature=exemplar-storage
      - --web.enable-remote-write-receiver
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '9090:9090'
    depends_on:
      - collector

  jaeger-service:
    image: jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest
    container_name: jaeger_service_container
    ports:
      - "5775:5775"
      - "5778:5778"
      - "14250:14250" # gRPC endpoint for OTLP
      - "14268:14268" # HTTP endpoint for OTLP
      - "16686:16686" # Jaeger UI
      - "14250:14250" # Jaeger gRPC endpoint
    environment:
      - COLLECTOR_OTLP_ENABLED=true

  grafana:
    container_name: grafana
    image: grafana/grafana
    volumes:
      - ./grafana/grafana.yml:/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/datasources.yml
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - prometheus
      - jaeger-service
    ```

